# Spring MVC redirect is rewritten from localhost to value in Host-Header

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, tomcat, redirect

I have an application (spring boot 2.5.6) where the user is able to request a REST resource with a callback uri as query parameter eg. `https://someservice/callback` or `http://localhost:5555/callback`. This works well if a user specifies a port which is not equal to the internal tomcat port (8080 in this case). However if the user defines an uri like `http://localhost:8080` he's not redirected to `http://localhost:8080/callback` but to the uri which was specified in the request Host-Header eg. `https://myservice.com/callback`:

Working as expected

```
GET https://myservice.com/foobar?callback=https://someotherservice/callback HTTP/1.1
Host: myservice.com
...

HTTP/1.1 303 
Location: https://someotherservice/callback?...
...
```

Working as expected

```
GET https://myservice.com/foobar?callback=http://localhost:5555/callback HTTP/1.1
Host: myservice.com
...

HTTP/1.1 303 
Location: http://localhost:5555/callback?...
...
```

Not working as expected

```
GET https://myservice.com/foobar?callback=http://localhost:8080/callback HTTP/1.1
Host: myservice.com
...

HTTP/1.1 303 
Location: https://myservice.com/callback?...
...
```

I'm not able to reproduce this behavior on my local machine (windows 10). This happens on our dev environment (debian buster). Any ideas who is rewriting the url (spring, tomcat?) and how I'm able to prevent this behavior? I tested it on a single instance to be sure it's not our loadbalancer.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just curious to know.  Is your Springboot app deployed on port 8080? or?

Comment: @SusanMustafa yes the embedded tomcat is running on port 8080 on the server. We have a nginx which routes the incoming requests corresponding. Maybe it's the nginx who's rewriting the host. This could explain why I'm not able to reproduce the behavior on my local machine. I'll have a look!

Comment: @SusanMustafa it's the nginx (https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) with proxy_redirect off; the client is correctly redirected to localhost:8080

Comment: Since the callback property is a query parameter....you must have some springboot logic that does the forwarding, could you show that code?  

I really want see if it is a Springboot code problem, or something external to Springboot like for example nginx or hosts file? 

Whoever is doing the "Callback" action is your culprit..

Comment: @SusanMustafa Sorry but I'm not allowed to share the code. But to clarify this it's not an application problem. The application returns correctly http://localhost:8080 and due to our nginx location / { proxy_pass            http://localhost:8080; .. the host is rewritten to the originally requested host (default behavior of the proxy_redirect option). We can fix this by setting proxy_redirect off; because we redirect to our own service in other usecases only with relative paths which are not rewritten.